# The "Key" attribute can only be used on an element that is contained in "IDictionary"

Tags: wpf, xaml

I'm getting the squiggly line under the 6th line of code below giving me the error stated in the title.  I just migrated to VS 2012 and everything was working fine in VS 2010.  I feel like maybe the problem is really elsewhere... can someone tell me if there is actually something wrong with this xaml?

```
<Application x:Class="SageWpf.App"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:SageWpf">
    <Application.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary x:Key="rd">
            <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
                <ResourceDictionary>
                    <local:AppBootStrapper x:Key="bootstrapper"/>
                    <local:EffectConverter x:Key="effectConverter"/>
                    <local:VisibilityConverter x:Key="visibilityConverter"/>
                </ResourceDictionary>
            </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
        </ResourceDictionary>


    </Application.Resources>
</Application>
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`<ResourceDictionary x:Key="rd">` is invalid. Remove the `x:Key` from there.

Also.. that's a bad way to structure your resources. Change it to:

```
<Application.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <local:AppBootStrapper x:Key="bootstrapper"/>
        <local:EffectConverter x:Key="effectConverter"/>
        <local:VisibilityConverter x:Key="visibilityConverter"/>
    </ResourceDictionary>
</Application.Resources>
```

Only use Merged Dictionaries if you have resources defined in another XAML file and you want to import them here.

Comment: Okay, I had wondered why it needed to be that way but left it since the Caliburn.Micro example did it with the merged dictionary.  Honestly I don't completely remember why I added the x:Key="rd" right now, but I could have sworn it was to fix some other error I had been getting... and I'm pretty sure it had been working in 2010 but maybe I'm just taking crazy pills.  The problem now is that I am still getting the same error with your solution, but the squiggly line is on the bootsrapper line.

Comment: I was partially mistaken... the error under the bootstrapper line was something entirely different and I got that fixed; however I am still getting the same original error message.  The squiggly line is just under the '<' character of the opening Appliction tag.

Comment: rebuild the entire solution.

Comment: Sigh... thanks.   I'm having some other weird troubles but at least this works now.